# Umbraco add CC while sending mails

Tags: api, email, umbraco

I want to add some emails(more than one) as CC while sending mails in umbraco.

I'm using this method: `umbraco.library.SendMail` but I don't find any options to add CC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umbraco's `SendMail()` helper method is (purposefully) very basic. It is actually only a few lines that creates a `MailMessage` instance with the `from` and `to` values and sends it via the `SmtpClient.Send()` method.

The `ToMail` parameter can actually accept multiple email addresses, presumably comma or semi-colon delimited. But these would not be CC recipients.

You would actually be be better off just creating your own method.

Comment: yes, you are right i got the same answer on Umbraco forums. http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/44125-Umbraco-add-CC-while-sending-mails